# What are the 'rules' for names with getters/settings in a class?

Tags: javascript

What are the restrictions on using getters and setters in javascript? For example, here are a few scenarios I've seen when just doing trial-and-error:

```js
class User {

    // 1 - must have an alias somewhere or will get loop
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    get name() {
        console.log('--- Getter ---');
        return this.name;
    }
    set name(name) {
        console.log('--- Setter --- ');
        this.name = name;
    }
}

const user = new User('David');
console.log(user.name);
```

```js
class User {

    name;

    // 2 - setter/getter must have a property with exact name in constructor?
    constructor(name) {
        this._name = name;
    }
    get name() {
        console.log('--- Getter ---');
        return this._name;
    }
    set name(name) {
        console.log('--- Setter --- ');
        this._name = name;
    }
}

const user = new User('David');
console.log(user.name);
user.name = 'Keith';
console.log(user.name);
```

Is a correct understanding of a setter/getter that:

1. The name must be aliased.
2. The setter/getter must have that exact name defined in the constructor.

Finally, putting it all togther, does the following seem like a good pattern to hide fields when user a getter/setter, as it seems like `#name` (private) and `name` (public) act like two different variables.

```js
class User {
    #name;
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    get name() {
        console.log('-getter-');
        return this.#name;
    }
    set name(name) {
        console.log('-setter-');
        this.#name = name
    }
}
bob = new User('Bob');
bob.name = 'Bobby';
console.log(bob.name);
```

Comment: "*What are the restrictions on using getters and setters in javascript?*" - there are none. "*The name must be aliased.*" - not sure what you mean by this, that a `.name` getter must not return `this.name`? Well, there's no rule against this, and it's not a syntax error either - it's just broken code, like a `while(true);` loop or recursion without a base case. "*The setter/getter must have that exact name defined in the constructor.*" - no, a constructor does not need to assign the property at all; you can also leave it uninitialised. Or even initialise the underlying `._name` directly.

Comment: @Bergi I see, thanks for the feedback. Would you want to show examples of the second case in an answer and I can accept that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A backing field is not a requirement, needless to say a backing field with the same name. You don't even need setter and getter if all you do is just setting and getting a backing field, since there would be functionally no difference than a normal field.

Getter and Setter are usually used when

1. the property is a computed property, e.g. derived from other properties/state.
2. you want to do extra work when accessing the field, e.g. notifying a property is changed

Example for case 1:

```js
class Foo
{
  constructor(bar)
  {
    this.bar = bar;
  }
  
  get barSquare()
  {
    return this.bar * this.bar;
  }
  
  set barSquare(x)
  {
    this.bar = Math.sqrt(x);
  }
}

let foo = new Foo(4);
console.log(foo.barSquare);
foo.barSquare = 25;
console.log(foo.bar);
```

Example for case 2:

You do need a backing field in this case, though the name of the backing field can be anything except the setter/getter name.

```js
class Foo
{
  constructor(bar)
  {
    this._bar = bar;
  }
  
  get bar()
  {
    return this._bar;
  }
  
  set bar(x)
  {
    console.log(`bar is changed to ${x}!`);
    this._bar = x;
  }
}

let foo = new Foo(4);
console.log(foo.bar);
foo.bar = 5;
console.log(foo.bar);
```

Finally, the parameter name (`bar`) defined in `constructor(bar)` is totally unrelated. It can be any legal variable name. It is scoped to the constructor block. For example, it can be

```js
class Foo
{
  constructor(totallyRandomName)
  {
    this.someBackingFieldName = totallyRandomName;
  }

  get bar()
  {
    return this.someBackingFieldName;
  }

  set bar(x)
  {
    console.log(`bar is changed to ${x}!`);
    this.someBackingFieldName = x;
  }
}

let foo = new Foo(4);
console.log(foo.bar);
foo.bar = 5;
console.log(foo.bar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving a stab at the comments from @Bergi:

> [ From question, incorrect assumption that] "The setter/getter must have that exact name defined in the constructor."

1. No, A constructor does not need to assign the property at all; you can also leave it uninitialised.

```js
class Person {
    name;
    set name(y) {
        console.log('setName');
        this.name = y;
    }
    get name() {
        console.log('getName');
        return this.name;
    }
}
let bob = new Person();
bob.name = 'Bob'
console.log(bob.name);
```

2. Or even initialise the underlying `._name` directly.

```js
class Person {
    constructor(x) {
        this.someOtherName = x;
    }
    set name(y) {
        console.log('setName');
        this.someOtherName = y;
    }
    get name() {
        console.log('getName');
        return this.someOtherName;
    }
}
let bob = new Person();
bob.name = 'Bob'
console.log(bob.name);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant